# Chrome Application Doesn't Use System Proxy

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy, google-chrome-app, network-monitoring

A Chrome Packaged Application under Windows 10 doesn't seem to be using my public proxy settings under Internet Options. I'm trying to monitor this application's network activity via Fiddler installed on another computer. Every HTTP and HTTPS requests are successfully monitored there, except the ones from this packaged application.

I'm pretty sure it uses HTTP requests behind, because I generated it from an Android APK file, using ARC Welder. And I can see HTTP requests from Android application itself on my phone. But not from generated packaged chrome application on Windows. Is there anything I can do with the manifest file or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Add its manifest.json to the question.

Comment: @wOxxOm Just a quick reminder, we're dealing with ARC here.

Comment: Well, my only guess was that the app may use `sockets` API directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome.sockets API does not use the Chrome browser proxy settings.
On ChromeOS, chrome.sockets will respect the system-wide VPN settings, however.